# Leaderboard Testing on Google Play Services

Tags: unity, android, leaderboards, debugging, google-play-services

I have a shared Google Play Developer account so that he allowed me to publish a game app. Next, I want to know if in order to test the online highscore is to upload the APK and publish it first before adding a new game at the *Game Services* section.

One thing, according to [*this link*](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards) and [*this link*](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) on setting up Google Play Services, these tutorials on implementing code for the leaderboard is possibly applied on the Manifest. Is it still the same in Unity if I added the lib folder onto the plugins folder of the Unity project and how?